# Google Analytics and the __utm.gif file

Tags: google-analytics

When using Google Analytics and using the newer ga.js file, is the __utm.gif file needed in your root directory of your web site?

I do see a call being made from my browswer to the file on google-analytics.com (http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?...), but in the past I was told that it needed to exist in the root of the site.

Does this still hold true?

Could you please provide a reference?

Comment: UPDATE: If you are ALSO using Urchin tracking with Google Analytics, the script at the bottom of the page must be modified to include the call to "pageTracker._setLocalRemoteServerMode()" and in doing so will require you to place the __utm.gif file in the root of you web application.  The script now looks like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-********-1");
  pageTracker._setLocalRemoteServerMode();
  pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>

Reference: http://www.google.com/support/urchin45/bin/answer.py?answer=28710

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the new version of the tracking code (`ga.js`), the **only thing** you need to do is [include this snippet of JavaScript](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=75129):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

This would imply that there are no requirements for you to host any `__utm.gif` file on your server (I'm not sure how this would even work for analytics anyway, as the whole point is for the client's browsers to make requests *to* Google's servers).

Comment: Right.  The way GA works is by making a specially-crafted request for a 1x1 image from Googles servers.  Google uses the url to obtain data about the current tracking event.

Answer (score 1):

I use the older urchin.js tracking mechansim and there are no requirements to host anything locally although you can put the .js file on your server for speed. There are four images that get requested to provide the tracking; `__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmc` and `__utmz` which correspond to they cookies recorded of the same name.

From Google; *[When you first begin implementing tracking in Google Analytics website, you need to install the tracking code on your website pages. The generic tracking code snippet consists of two parts: a script tag that references the ga.js tracking code, and another script that executes the tracking code.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingOverview.html)*

Answer (score 1):

You are required to add _utm.gif to your server root if you are also sending a copy of the google analytics data to your local webserver. It gives you the option of keep the data much longer since Google is only keeping 25 months of data for free account. 
Google also doesn't share the raw data, the only way to get the raw data is also sending it to your local webserver log. For it to work, you need to add this line below to the tracking code:

_gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);

For more detailed discussion, please refer to the book by Clifton, Brian (2012-03-30). Advanced Web Metrics with Google Analytics (Kindle Locations 4459-4460). John Wiley and Sons.