# What's image request with get parameters

Tags: http, google-analytics

While trying to understand how does the [google keyword tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=6116085536&__u=2263864376&__o=cues&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS) is requesting data I have found that it has a request for a .gif file with GET arguments.. for example:

```
https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=&utms=&utmn=&utmhn=&utmt=&utme=&utmcs=utmsr=&utmvp=&utmsc=&utmul=&utmje=&utmfl=&utmdt=&utmhid=&utmr=&utmp=&utmac=&utmcc=&utmu=
```

(*I have omitted all argument's data*)

can someone please explain?

Comment: What do you not understand about it? Please clarify.

Comment: why does a none script file such as gif gets arguments who actually aren't suppose to have any effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This GET request gets handled by Google's analytics servers. It probably doesn't just directly serve __utm.gif from somewhere on the filesystem; it probably executes a script that takes all the parameters, does some processing, and logs that request in their analytics database, and *then* serves a 1x1 transparent GIF.

Comment: So if I understand it right the server is programmed to call some script file every time this picture is requested with the request arguments right?
If so what can it give me that the result is a transparent gif picture and not real data as I would expect to receive?
thanx

Comment: What do you mean 'real data'? A script can serve anything it wants to serve.

Comment: By real data I mean some data for the client side to be seen.
And not a binary picture which doesn't give us a thing.

Comment: Images are 'real data' too. When you make an HTTP request for an image it serves back the image file (along with some HTTP headers).

Comment: you are right I shouldn't have used these words.
but how can I get from a small picture such as the one that Im getting back so many data on words and their statistics...

Comment: The picture doesn't actually hold any relevant data. All the analytics data is stored somewhere in a database on Google's servers.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a request, it's purpose is to send analytics data in the query string parameters. For a good explanation, see [Why does Google Analytics use __utm.gif?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170190/why-does-google-analytics-use-utm-gif).

For more detail on what the actual parameters on the GIF request are, see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gifParameters