# Prevent /p/__utm.gif caused by Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am receiving a 404 error from my Google Analytics tracking code. The following is the code I am currently using in the footer of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']); 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 

(function() { 
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'ssl' : 'www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
})(); 

</script>
```

The 404 error appears to be caused by: /p/__utm.gif

I was using the same JS code from this question: [Google Analytics and the __utm.gif file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227417/google-analytics-and-the-utm-gif-file). However, that didn't work with my last report from Goolge.

Is there other way to do it?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Are you saying that the GA's tracking pixel is not resolving from Google's servers? Could you provide an example of usage? I'll help edit your question if I can understand what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I will owe you for this :). I'm trying to get help to prevent the 404 error page caused when I ran the report from Google analytic every whit, It occurs under /p/__utm.gif.I'm not sure why it happened.

Comment: I added the JS code from the lick I post in me question

Comment: once I had the /browserconfig.xml. so I just added to my pages the meta tag "<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"/>" to solve  it, but here I couldn;t find a way

Comment: Do you have an example of your implementation? If you are using the new version of GA you shouldn't need to add anything other then the tracking snippet. I'd like to take a look at your implementation to verify you have the correct tracking code. If there is anything special you are trying to track, you should mention that as well.

Comment: A side question, what report is it that you are running that causes this error? Also, what does this have to do with "Java"? did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60020/discussion-between-aliendev-and-samarland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older tracking snippet from GA. You should update to the latest version as it should solve your problem. You should also ensure that this tracking code is on all of your pages on your site. The latest code snippet looks more like the following:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

You can get a formatted snippet for your site by:

1. logging into GA (Google Analytics)
2. Going to the admin UI by selecting the "Admin" tab at the top of the interface
3. If you have multiple accounts, ensure you have the correct account selected on the left (Account) column of this screen
4. Select the site you need the snippet for in the center (Property) column.
5. Select "Tracking Info" and then "Tracking Code" from the middle column.
6. The column should animate to the left and a new bit should appear that contains your tracking code formatted and completed for your site.
7. Copy and paste this into every page on your site.

Comment: I have a question, If the users who visiting a website go mistakenly to wrong URLs and got the 404 page error that I have redirect to it. Is the GA report me when I execute the GA for that?

Comment: if the 404 error has the tracking code, and it resolves before the redirect (such as the meta methods or js), then yes it will show in the GA report. However, if you setup a 301 redirect (either in htaccess or your sites apache definition for example) for a URL that people are consistently going to and getting a 404, then the 404 will not resolve, therefor it didn't happen. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yeah, it does. Does the script that you posted here resolve the redirect or there's another? I want to execute the GA with no result about /p/__utm.gif(404 error). Is there a script for this purpose?

Comment: well, here is the thing with that. You now have records of this 404 error. The only way to make it go away now, is to not include the time frame in which you had the old analytics code running. I would suggest making an event to mention that you updated the analytics snippet to the latest code, and that it fixed the /p/__utm.gif 404 error.

Comment: oh, So the event will update the snippet to latest code before the analytic will run? I guess this event will get more specific info from that report, You will help me more if you provide me more info of how to make it.